# How to define a generic List in an abstract super class?

Tags: java, generics

I'm trying to create an abstract class with an abstract method, which should be able to return any type of a list with items extending a `SuperBean`.

Later I then want to create a generic class which can add items to that lists.
Example:

```
class AbstractService<T extends SuperBean> {
    //this is what I'm aiming for
    void add(T item) {
        // "is not applicable for the arguments (T)"
        superBean.getSublist().add(item);
    }
}

abstract class SuperBean {
    abstract List<? extends SuperBean> getSublist();
}

class MyBean1 extends SuperBean {
    List<MyBean2> sublist;

    List<MyBean2> getSublist() {
        return sublist;
    }
}

class MyBean2 extends SuperBean {
    List<MyBean3> sublist;

    List<MyBean3> getSublist() {
            return sublist;
        }
}
```

Question: how to I have to define the `abstract getSublist()` class so that I can add any `T item` that is an implementation of `SuperBean`?

Comment: What is the problem defining the field as `List<MyBean>`? Looks like you want to obtain `MyBean2 mb2 = aSuperBean.getItem();` and `MyBean3 mb3 = aSuperBean.getItem();`, which will be wrong.

Comment: No I need the specific class types like `MyBean2` for the sublists.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you are aiming for, but you could try something like this: `public abstract class GenericList<T> extends ArrayList<T>`

Comment: What is the declaration of `superBean` in your `AbstractService.add` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to add to your generics in `AbstractService`:

```
//        Add S to be T's type parameter         Add <S> to SuperBean here
class AbstractService<S extends SuperBean, T extends SuperBean<S>> {
    // I'm assuming superBean is defined here.
    T superBean;

    //this is what I'm aiming for
    void add(S item) {
        superBean.getSublist().add(item);
    }
}
```

Next, you will need to make `SuperBean` generic, with its subclasses defining the generic type parameter `<T>`:

```
abstract class SuperBean<T extends SuperBean> {
    // Now you can define the abstract method properly:
    abstract List<T> getSublist();
}
```

Each subclass defines its generic type parameter appropriately:

```
class MyBean1 extends SuperBean<MyBean2> {
    List<MyBean2> sublist;

    List<MyBean2> getSublist() {
        return sublist;
    }
}
```

And `MyBean2` is defined similarly:

```
class MyBean2 extends SuperBean<MyBean3> {
    List<MyBean3> sublist;

    List<MyBean3> getSublist() {
            return sublist;
    }
}
```

This allows you to declare services as follows:

```
AbstractService<MyBean2, MyBean1> service1 = new AbstractService<MyBean2, MyBean1>();
AbstractService<MyBean3, MyBean2> service2 = new AbstractService<MyBean3, MyBean2>();
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that `MyBean1` does not extend `SuperBean<MyBean1>`, so it cannot be used in `AbstractService`.

Comment: While this compiles and runs, you can add a `MyBean2` instance in a `MyBean3` list.

Comment: IMO this design is wrong. An abstract more generic class should not change the state of a subclass that points to specific data. Check my first comment on question.

Comment: @PaulBellora I had to make `S` extends a raw `SuperBean`; `S extends SuperBean<S>` wouldn't work in instantiating an `AbstractService`.  With `AbstractService<MyBean2, MyBean1> service = new AbstractService<MyBean2, MyBean1>();`, I would get an error that `MyBean2` is not within its bound; should extend `SuperBean<MyBean2>`, but it really extends `SuperBean<MyBean3>`.  That would seem to force another type parameter fit for `MyBean3`, and this would continue ad infinitum.  At somepoint, some type parameter must extend a raw `SuperBean`, and adding just `S` here is sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

Your generic parameters don't make sense here. If you make the generic types explicit, you can see where it's going wrong:

Add the generic parameter to your `SuperBean`:

```
abstract class SuperBean<T extends SuperBean> {
    abstract List<T> getSublist();
}
```

and make that type explicit in the subtypes:

```
class MyBean1 extends SuperBean<MyBean2> {
    List<MyBean2> sublist;

    List<MyBean2> getSublist() {
        return sublist;
    }
}
```

Now, in your service, you would have

```
class AbstractService<T extends SuperBean<S>> {

    void add(T item) {
        // you cannot do this because the items in the sublist of 
        // your super bean are of the wrong type.
        superBean.getSublist().add(item);
    }
}
```

The alternative would be to make the service as

```
class AbstractService<T extends SuperBean<T>>
```

Then you would be able to add items to the sublist, but your beans are not of the right type. For instance, `MyBean1` does not extend `SuperBean<MyBean1>`, but it extends `SuperBean<MyBean2>`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you want, but doesn't produce errors.

There are two abstract declarations, SuperBean and AbstractService  (though AbstractService is defined, I assume that it should be abstract).

There are three declarations that are not abstract, MyBean{1,2,3}

I define awSuperBean just to see if it works.

The code you pasted doesn't have a (-grr- concrete) superBean defined yet. So, I define a superBean called awSuperBean and use it in the (abstract?) add method.

.
.

```
///  testing superbean implementation
//
class awSuperBean<MyBean1> extends SuperBean {
    List<MyBean1>  getSublist() { return new java.util.ArrayList<MyBean1>(); }
}
//
///

class AbstractService<T extends SuperBean> {

/// tests a superbean definition
//
    awSuperBean<T> asuperBean;

    //this is what I'm aiming for
    void add(T item) {
        // "is not applicable for the arguments (T)"

/// use the superbean
        asuperBean.getSublist().add(item);
    }
}

/// every defined SuperBean subtype will need to specify the type 
//  of SuperBean it will produce in it's getSublist call
// 
abstract class SuperBean<getSublist extends SuperBean> {  

/// use the type parameter
//
    abstract List<getSublist> getSublist();
}
```

I think you should only use the parametric type identifier, T, in the abstract classes. Use the declared types in the superbean subtype definitions instead of confusing Ts.